How do I setup And keyword in the vs code

I am using vs code for project and what's happening is all gherkin keyword are working but only "And" is not working I am using 1.82 version of Vs code
And should work is my expectation
Can someone provide me input on this please

Do you check the language mode? Check the .feature file, is it set to Gherkin?
